# Horizontal footer in a collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm working in a `CollectionView` which is horizontal:

[image]

I can do this easily with a `CollectionView` except for the label '6 day streak', I was thinking that view is a footer but in a horizontal `CollectionView`, this appears in the top or in the bottom in a portrait mode.

I was thinking to create a `ScrollView` under this `CollectionView` and to move both at same time, but I don't know if it's a horrible idea.

I think this is not possible with Flow Layout and I'm not an expert of Custom Layout, is this posible?

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You should create a custom UICollectionViewLayout.  It's not that hard.

Comment: I think, Just I should tweak layout attributes, so should I create a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout instead of a custom UICollectionViewLayout?

Comment: Yes, you could add a supplementary view for the "6 day streak" bubble to a UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass.

Answer (score 0):

It is old question, but I leave solution for some other people who have same problem.

You can make footer always horizontally located in last, subclassing your UICollectionViewFlowLayout and overriding layoutAttributesForElementsInRect().

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    if let layoutAttributesForElementsInRect = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect), let collectionView = self.collectionView {

      for layoutAttributes in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect {
            if layoutAttributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter {

                let section = layoutAttributes.indexPath.section
                let numberOfItemsInSection = collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(section)

                if numberOfItemsInSection > 0 {
                    let lastCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: max(0, numberOfItemsInSection - 1), inSection: section)

                    if let lastCellAttrs = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(lastCellIndexPath) {
                        var origin = layoutAttributes.frame.origin

                        origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(lastCellAttrs.frame)

                        layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1024
                        layoutAttributes.frame.origin = origin
                        layoutAttributes.frame.size = layoutAttributes.frame.size
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return layoutAttributesForElementsInRect
    }

    return nil
}
```